# SSRS showing wrong data after deploying report

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2012

I am having this problem where the data being shown in report is different when I deploy it on server. So let's say if I am viewing report by pressing F5 (to debug) or by clicking on "Preview" button on the report in BI Studio the data shown is correct. But when I deploy the same report and when I run it from server such as `http://myserver/reports` then data shown is incorrect/missing.

For e.g. in some cases it is not showing data for a particular field and there are some number fields which are showing wrong data. I have cleaned the solution, deleted data cache files, rebuilt and deployed like 100 times but no luck.

When I deploy it shows some warning (which I guess I can ignore) but no errors.

I have checked the database by running queries and stored procedures directly and they all return correct data.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: have you checked the deployed report data sources, are they connecting to the right database on the right server?

Comment: Yes I have checked it on report server that it is connecting to right database.

Comment: Ok taking a cue from your comment I was able to solve this problem. I went to report server and looked at the XML of one of the data set which was creating problem and found out that the new FIELD I have added is not there. Then I tried to deploy that data set and it said Overwrite Dataset property is set to False and that's why it was not deploying and I missed it in messages when it deploys a solution. So I simply set the property to True, deployed it and viola problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to report server and looked at the XML of one of the data set which was creating problem and found out that the new FIELD I have added is not there. Then I tried to deploy that data set and it said Overwrite Dataset property is set to False and that's why it was not deploying and I missed it in messages when it deploys a solution. So I simply set the property to True, deployed it and viola problem is solved.